# A few questions about the blockchain and smart contracts

Tags: blockchain

for my new job I am currently to investigate into blockchain. I have red many articles and saw many videos on what it is and how to implement it, but it seemed like some very vital questions remain unanswered to me. They would be the following:

1. Very crucial: Where exactly is the DATA of the BLOCKCHAIN stored?
   Okay, so of course I know that every node in the chain has a copy of the ledger that is constantly updated. But this ledger, as far as my understanding goes, ONLY includes data about TRANSACTIONS, but not the actual data loaded into the blockchain? Or is this the same, since the BLOCKCHAIN can not store, say a "video" but only data about bitcoins transactions?
2. Either way, that means that the public blockchain is getting bigger in size by the minute. When every node stores the whole blockchain, it is only a matter of time until it all crashes since no one has enough room to store everything anymore, right?
3. Regarding smart contracts: It is my understanding that a smart contract is the only way to access the blockchain. If I wanted to set up my own blockchain, what I am doing is programming a smart contract that then accesses a server and loads data into the chain. Is this correct?
4. How many "public" blockchains exist? Is it just this one? Or is there one public blockchain for every topic?

I hope you guys can bring some clearity into my questions!

Regards,

J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> for my new job I am currently to investigate into blockchain

The main question is why? Why are you looking into blockchain is there a specific application that blockchain is supposed to solve? It is usually not the silver bullet.

Also the definition of blockchain varies wildly based on context. For example, it may be a chain of blocks, but is there a consensus mechanism? Does it use proof of work, proof of stake, some other mechanism? Is it permissioned or permission-less? Is it public or private? The "chain of blocks" technology invented in Bitcoin was designed to provide distributed consensus of transaction data in a public, permission-less system. Any other system doesn't really need that technology.

> 1.) Very crucial: Where exactly is the DATA of the BLOCKCHAIN stored? Okay, so of course I know that every node in the chain has a copy of the ledger that is constantly updated. But this ledger, as far as my understanding goes, ONLY includes data about TRANSACTIONS, but not the actual data loaded into the blockchain? Or is this the same, since the BLOCKCHAIN can not store, say a "video" but only data about bitcoins transactions?

Bitcoin only stores transaction data (and meta data of each block such as block hash, timestamp, etc.), See [Blocks](https://jbaczuk.github.io/blockchain_fundamentals/2-Fundamentals/2.1-Blocks.html). Some transactions use [`OP_RETURN` scripts](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/OP_RETURN) which allow storing arbitrary data and has been used to store photos, links, etc., but this has been a topic for debate as to whether it is good for the network to have all of this non-transaction-related data replicated across all full nodes.

> 2.) Either way, that means that the public blockchain is getting bigger in size by the minute. When every node stores the whole blockchain, it is only a matter of time until it all crashes since no one has enough room to store everything anymore, right?

Assuming that data storage technology is stagnant and prices stay the same, yes. But that has obviously not been the case, so the hope is that it scales with the system. Also, you can run a light node, in which case the data is validated, but once it is validated it is discarded (generally speaking).

> 3.) Regarding smart contracts: It is my understanding that a smart contract is the only way to access the blockchain. If I wanted to set up my own blockchain, what I am doing is programming a smart contract that then accesses a server and loads data into the chain. Is this correct?

Bitcoin uses a scripting system for determining who can spend bitcoin (like locking it to a key pair, which must provide a valid signature. You can write scripts that could be considered smart contracts. Others like Ethereum have extended the concept for a turing-complete language. To send data (i.e. submit transactions) you must provide a valid transaction that has valid scripts or it will be rejected.

> 4.) How many "public" blockchains exist? Is it just this one? Or is there one public blockchain for every topic?

There are many applications (probably thousands) that say they are a public blockchain, and which use similar (or the exact same) technology as Bitcoin.

Comment: in addition, when storing DATA in the blockchain, also consider that - as a side effect of storing them in the blockchain, you are sharing the data with the blockchain nodes. Even if encrypted, this could be an issue for legal experts because of GDPR (DSGVO). You need strategies you control with whom you are sharing data, and how to delete or destroy data. Probably you also need to geoblock nodes from outside EU territory. etc.... In my understanding, this is difficult in a blockchain.  This becomes an issue as soon as you are storing personnel data.